# Keeping font sizes when converting DOCX to HTML using mammoth

Tags: python, mammoth

I have the following code that converts DOCX to HTML:

```
style_map = """
            u => u
        """
f = open(file + ".docx", 'rb')
b = open(file + '.html', 'wb')
document = mammoth.convert_to_html(f, style_map=style_map)
html = document.value
b.write(html.encode('utf8'))
f.close()
b.close()
```

The output looks good, however in the HTML all font sizes are the same where in the DOCX there are some bigger and smaller fonts.
How can I save to HTML keeping the relative sizes of the font?